# Server not responding for only long requests. Underlying connection was closed. ReadResponse() failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, request, response

I have tried the following solutions:

1) Increase timeout in client request.

2) Increase server ExecutionTimeout in web.config HTTPRuntime tag.

3) I have tried using both ASMX and WCF services. Even when the server page takes time (code behind), an error appears `"ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request."`.

4) Change the application pool timeouts from IIS.

5) Change the IIS > My website > HTTP response header > Set common headers > Enable/Disable HTTP alive

I am using following code to test server timeout issue:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string LongRequest(int delaySeconds)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(delaySeconds*1000);
        return "Delayed for " + delaySeconds + " Seconds";
    }
```

We have different servers but this issue is appearing only on one server.

Note! This issue only appears when a request takes more than 40 seconds. (this time is not specific as it increases decreases everytime)

Comment: did you check iis server logs?

Comment: networking issues?

Comment: @AntonNorko Thanks for the suggeston.I have added a server code to log in text file, and server code is writing log even after 2minutes, but the client get failed response in around 40secs

Comment: @bradbury9 Server is writing log after the operation completion. Seems like networking issue or iis setting not to take long time request. Any suggestion regarding iis settings or what can i check further?

Comment: I think Anton suggested not to write specific logs, but checking already generated IIS logs, by default it logs all the request, who made them and the http code status. If it is not configured otherwise, they are located in C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1

Comment: @bradbury9, yes, you right. I meant common IIS logs.

Comment: iis logs for that server are not enabled and unfortunately i am not allowed to enable iis logs for that live cloud server.

Comment: Issue is not appearing while accessing the application from inside the server using localhost but appears when to access using URL/IP Address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. I figured out that server switches were configured to close longer requests. I have now used internal IP of the server (which is accessible from our other servers only).